# re.VERBOSE with embedded space fails to compile

Tags: regex, python-re

```
import re
re.compile(r"(?: *)", flags=re.VERBOSE)
```

raises `re.error: nothing to repeat at position 4`.  Any of the following compile fine:

```
re.compile(r"(?:\ *)", flags=re.VERBOSE)
re.compile(r"(?:[ ]*)", flags=re.VERBOSE)
re.compile(r"(?: *)")
```

The [docs for VERBOSE](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html) say "Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except ... within tokens like *?, (?: or (?P<...>." but it seems not to be honoring the "(?:" part.  Is this a library bug, or am I just not getting my head around what the docs mean?

I can reproduce this on either:

- Python 3.9.13 / MacOS 12.6.1 (Monterey)
- Python 3.9.2 / Debian 11.5 (bullseye)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important details of the documentation:

The "ignore, except" does not necessarily mean a correct pattern. It means the whitespace is taken into account.

Moreover, the wording is "within tokens". As the documentation also says (immediately after your citation): "For example, (? : and * ? are not allowed." Notice the whitespace appears "inside" the tokens, not afterwards.

If you run `re.compile(r"(?:*)", flags=re.VERBOSE)` (i.e. whitespace removed), you will get the same error (though now at position 3).

Comment: Heh.  It looks like that extra comment was added in 3.10 (https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/24908f1f207f4642fc57ae79c69a3dcb0770a96a)